# Problem with MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have 2 tables:

The question table with the following structure:

```
id
title
userid
date
```

and answers table with the following structure:

```
id
idquestion
userid
message
date
```

I want to show all the questions and the latest answer to that question.

For example, if we have 5 questions, I would like to get something like this:

```
id    title   message   messagedate
1     qs 1    mess 1    2010-11-18
2     qs 2    mess 2    2010-11-19
3     qs 3    mess 3    2010-11-20
4     qs 4    mess 4    2010-11-21
```

My query so far:

```
    SELECT q.id, qa.id as answerid, title, qa.message 
      FROM `questions` q 
INNER JOIN questions_answers qa 
        ON q.id = qa.idquestion 
  GROUP BY q.id 
  ORDER BY q.id, answerid DESC
```

But it doesn't work correctly, it groups by the question id(removing all the other columns messages, leaving only the first message - so the order by is useless)

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you post some sample data to the tables, to show exactly how you want the output to be generated from the stored data?  (For example, simply removing the `GROUP BY` appears to work now, but I don't think that's what you ultimately want)...

Comment: If I remove the group by, I'll get all the answers. For example if I have one question with 2 answers, I'll have 2 rows showing up for that question, instead of one. If I have X questions, I want to get X rows when doing the query, so only the latest answer / question,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old problem. Here's the solution:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

In your case:

```
SELECT q.id, qa.id as answerid, title, qa.message 
FROM questions q
JOIN questions_answers qa ON q.id = qa.idquestion
LEFT JOIN questions_answers qa2 ON qa.idquestion = qa2.idquestion AND qa.date < qa2.date
WHERE qa2.idquestion IS NULL
```

(The idea is to split the problem in two operations: One join from questions to answers and then use the methods from the MySQL article.)

Comment: I would like to do it only with 1 query, no subqueries.

Comment: Then maybe just use the solution with the LEFT JOIN!?

Comment: I have two different tables, not only one as that example has. So, I can't figure out how to do it. Can you help me a bit with the query? Thanks,

Comment: As I don't have your data I cannot test my query, but I added my best guess to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could approach it a different way.  You are using an inner join, which means you won't show questions with no answer anyway, so search for max answer grouped by question id, and join questions table to get the title.

`SELECT 
    q.id, qa.id as answerid, q.title, qa.message 
FROM 
    questions q
    INNER JOIN question_answers qa ON q.id = qa.idquestion AND qa.id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM question_answers WHERE idquestion = q.id)
GROUP BY 
    q.id
ORDER BY 
    q.id DESC`

Comment: That works quite fine for the qa.id, but the qa.message is wrong, still the first one. For example I want to find the last user that replied to that message, the MAX won't work here,

Comment: Nope, that will give an arbitrary message for qa.message, not the most recent one.

Comment: I tested and yeah, the message was messed up, here it is, functional with a subquery, but its not as pretty as AndreKR's :p